# I am looking for a way to delete files in a specific order: delete 2, skip 3, delete 2, skip 3, etc

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

I am working with an interlaced video file that I have created an image sequence from. My goal is to delete the interlaced frames, which in my folder, is 2 interlaced images, followed by 3 non-interlaced images.

Is there an easy way to go about deleting the interlaced files with that pattern (delete 2 sequentially, then skip the next 3, delete the next 2, skip the next 3, etc.)?

The files are numbered sequentially (`000001`-`XXXXXX`).
So basically I would want to delete:

```
000001
000002
```

Then keep:

```
000003
000004
000005
```

Then delete:

```
000006
000007
```

And so on.

Comment: What version of Windows? PowerShell would be a better choice. Try this code in a PowerShell console opened to the folder containing your frames: `gci -af | %{ $Index = [Int]$_.BaseName.Split('-')[0]; [PSCustomObject]@{ 'Index' = $Index; 'Name' = $_.Name; 'Delete' = $Index % 5 -in @(1,2) }}`

Answer (score 0):

If the name of your files starts with the last digit equal to **`1`**, I understand that it is necessary to exclude all files that end with the digits:

```
  1,2,6,7

  000001
  000002
  000003
  000004
  000005
  000006
  000007
  000008
  000009
  000010
```

1. The command **`where`** with the flag **`??????`**, will list all files starting with 0 and which have 6 digits/characters.

   - To list all files between 000001-000100, but only those ending in 5:

   > ```
   > F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256>where .:?????5
   > F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000005
   > F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000015
   > F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000025
   > F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000035
   > F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000045
   > F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000055
   > F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000065
   > F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000075
   > F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000085
   > F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000095
   > ```
2. Use a simple loop **`for`** and list the digits one by one and use them to determine which of your files should be excluded because their names end with a predefined number

```bat
@For %G in (1,2,6,7)...
```

3. Add a `For /F` loop to use the output from the listing by the`where` command composing with it the command to delete your files:

```bat
 @For /F %i in ('where .:?????%G')do @echo/del "%i"
```

4. Check if the `echo` output is correct, if so, remove the **<strike>`echo`</strike>** for effective **deletion** of your files by command `del`:

```bat
 @For /F %i in ('where .:?????%G')do echo/@del "%i"
```

---

- For command line:

```bat
@For %G in (1,2,6,7)do @For /F %i in ('where .:?????%G')do @del "%i"
```

- For bat/cmd file:

```bat
@echo off 

For %%G in (1,2,6,7)do For /F %%i in ('
where.exe .:?????%%~G')do del /q "%%~i"
```

---

- File not deleted between 000001-000100 and listed by number order
  sequentially by commmand: **`where .:??????|sort`**

> ```bat
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000003
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000004
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000005
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000008
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000009
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000010
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000013
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000014
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000015
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000018
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000019
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000020
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000023
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000024
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000025
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000028
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000029
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000030
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000033
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000034
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000035
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000038
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000039
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000040
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000043
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000044
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000045
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000048
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000049
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000050
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000053
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000054
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000055
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000058
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000059
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000060
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000063
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000064
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000065
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000068
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000069
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000070
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000073
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000074
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000075
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000078
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000079
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000080
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000083
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000084
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000085
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000088
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000089
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000090
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000093
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000094
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000095
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000098
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000099
> F:\SUPER_USER\Q1556256\000100
> ```

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[For](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**

  [√] **[For /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

  [√] **[Find](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)**

  [√] **[Where](https://www.petri.com/using-where-exe)**

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell, per my earlier ( unanswered ) comments. Seeing now that you were descirbing a range rather than a hypehnated filename when you typed `000000-xxxxxx` makes things even easier.

Verbose:

```
$Source = 'c:\folder\path'
Get-ChildItem $Source -File | Where {
   [Int]$_.Name % 5 -in @(1,2)
} | Remove-Item
```

Compact:

```
gci 'c:\folder\path' -af | ? { [Int]$_.Name % 5 -in @(1,2) } | ri
```

[Get-ChildItem/gci](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem)

[Where-Object/?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object)

[Remove-Item/ri](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item)

[% (Modulus)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arithmetic_operators?view=powershell-7)

[-in](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7#-in)

[@(1,2)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7#the-array-sub-expression-operator)

### Sample:

```
PS C:\...\seldel>gci -name
000001
000002
000003
000004
000005
000006
000007
000008
000009
000010
000011
000012
000013
000014
000015
000016
000017
000018
000019
000020
000021
000022
000023
000024
000025
PS C:\...\seldel>gci -af | ? { [Int]$_.Name % 5 -in @(1,2) } | ri
PS C:\...\seldel>gci -name
000003
000004
000005
000008
000009
000010
000013
000014
000015
000018
000019
000020
000023
000024
000025
PS C:\...\seldel>
```